# Given some of the roots of the function $f(x) = x^3+bx^2+cx+d$, how do I find the coefficients of that function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Two of the roots of $f(x) = x^3+bx^2+cx+d$ are $3$ and $2+i$. How do I find b+c+d? The answer choices are -7, -5, 6, 9, and 25.

Comment: Are $b,c$ and $d$ real numbers?

Comment: Yes, they are all real numbers.

Comment: Then the other root is $2-i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cubic polynomial will have three roots. We were given all three roots, since $f(2+i)=0 \space \implies \space f(2-i)=0$. Now we can factor the cubic and write $$x^3+bx^2+cx+d = (x-3)(x-(2+i))(x-(2-i))$$ Once you expand the RHS you can easily find $b,c,d$.

Answer (score 0):

x^3+bx^2+cx+d = 0 has 3 solutions 3 and 2+i are given. third solution z is not.

this polynomial can decomposed as (x-3)(x-2-i)(x-z)=0 from here follows
1. 3*(2+i)*z = -d
2. 3z + 3(2+i) + z(2+i) = c
3. 3 + 2+i + z = -b

these admits a solution:
 b = -5 - i - z;
 c = 6 + 3 i + 5 z + i z, 
 d = -3 z(2 + i)
in order b to be real z = y-i
in order d to be real y = 2;

so b = -7;
c = 17;
d = -15;

Comment: The third solution is given, because if one root is complex, its conjugate is also a root.